# Use of Factory Pattern in Spring Batch FileHeaderFieldSetMapper

Tags: spring-batch, factory-pattern

I am setting up a Spring Batch job which would process a multi-record file. One of the record is having the following  structure.

```
Ind,RecCode,AccNum,RecTypeDesc,EffectiveDate,CreditAmount,DebitAmount,BatchNumber,NumberOfTrasactions 
5, 20, 100, prl, 12084, as0, 0, 3, 1
```

Depending upon the value in the RecordCode field, it will be either a payment record or a reversal record.

I am setting up the **PatternMatchingCompositeLineMapper** to read the record types in the file. I have created the following 2 FieldSetMapper implementations classes

```
@Component("paymentBatchFieldSetMapper")
public class  PaymentBatchFieldSetMapper implements FieldSetMapper<PaymentBatch> {

    @Override
    public PaymentBatch mapFieldSet(FieldSet fieldSet) throws BindException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

and second one as,

```
@Component("reversalBatchFieldSetMapper")
public class  ReversalBatchFieldSetMapper implements FieldSetMapper<PaymentBatch> {

    @Override
    public PaymentBatch mapFieldSet(FieldSet fieldSet) throws BindException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

I have created a factory class as following to return either of the above 2 as below

```
@Component("achBatchFieldSetMapperFactory")
public class ACHBatchFieldSetMapperFactory {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public FieldSetMapper<? extends AbstractACHBatch> getFieldSetMapper(RecordTypeDescription recordTypeDescription) {
        FieldSetMapper<? extends AbstractACHBatch> fieldSetMapper = null;
        switch(recordTypeDescription) {
        case PAYMENT:
            fieldSetMapper = applicationContext.getBean(PaymentBatchFieldSetMapper.class);
            break;
        case REVERSAL:
            fieldSetMapper = applicationContext.getBean(ReversalBatchFieldSetMapper.class);
            break;
        }
        return fieldSetMapper;
    }
}
```

Below is the bean configuration for the map object to be injected into PatternMatchingCompositeLineMapper.

```
@Bean
public Map<String, LineTokenizer> fieldSetMapperMap(FileHeaderFieldSetMapper fileHeaderFieldSetMapper, PaymentBatchFieldSetMapper paymentBatchFieldSetMapper,
        ReversalBatchFieldSetMapper reversalBatchFieldSetMapper) {
    Map<String, FieldSetMapper> map = new HashMap<String, FieldSetMapper>();
    map.put("1*", fileHeaderFieldSetMapper);
    map.put("5*", ?????);                   
}
```

Is there a possibility that I can use the factory to return the needed FieldSet mapper depending upon the record in the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The item reader is designed to return one type of items at a time. Let's imagine we manage to map records to either `PaymentBatch` or `ReversalBatch` according to the `RecordCode` field, this means that after the mapping occurs, the `ItemReader` would return two types. This is not possible by design.

What you can do is create a POJO that has a one-to-one mapping with the fields in your input file, then use a `ClassifierCompositeItemProcessor` to process each item according to its type (The classifier would be based on the `RecordTypeDescription` enum in your case).

*NB:* It is of course technically possible to forget about the generic type of the `ItemReader<T>` interface and make the item reader return `Object`s, but this would require ugly usage of `instanceof` in your processor to determine the record type. I highly recommend **not** using this approach.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your direction. I am facing 1 problem in configuring the ItemProcessor using classifier for which I would ask a another question.

Comment: You can find examples of the `ClassifierCompositeItemProcessor` here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-infrastructure/src/test/java/org/springframework/batch/item/support/ClassifierCompositeItemProcessorTests.java. They show the usage of `PatternMatchingClassifier` and `SubclassClassifier`. In your case, a custom classifier would takes the object (that maps one-to-one to your file) and according to the value of its `RecordTypeDescription` it would return the item processor of either `PaymentBatch` or `ReversalBatch`.